# React: onBlur handler/callback not working as expected - Called function and function as a reference at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-microservice-tyobc

So I have a text input react component with an `onBlur`.  This contains a `handleBlur` function, and an `onBlurCallback` function that gets passed in.

They work as I would expect them to individually

```
const MyInput = ({ onBlurCallback }) => { ... }

<input onBlur={e => handleBlur(e} />
<input onBlur={onBlurCallback} />
```

But when I try combining them, that's where I run into issues..  My callback fires as I would expect, but my handleBlur doesn't fire at all.

```
<MyInput onBlur={
    (e => {
        handleBlur(e);
    },
    onBlurCallback)
} />
```

Feel like I'm missing something super obvious...  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you do it like this

```
const MyInput = ({handleBlur, onBlurCallback}) => {
  return (
    <input onBlur={e => {
      handleBlur(e);
      onBlurCallback();
    }} />
  )
} 

<MyInput handleBlur={blurHandler} onBlurCallback={blurCallback} />
```

Otherwise you should provide a better code example with the exact `MyInput` definition and how you're using it.

Comment: Here's a quick sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-microservice-tyobc

My issue with that solution is I need to define the parameters passed into the `onBlurCallback` otherwise it fails.  

I think I might be misunderstanding something - But there's 2 `onBlur` examples in that link, to show where I'm having trouble.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with passing `e`.  But I'm not sure what the solution is there?  I guess `onBlurCallback(e)` would work - But that doesn't seem right?

Comment: I don't see what would be wrong with passing arguments to your functions. You could also just calll `onBlurCallback` inside `handleBlur`. That way you can say `onBlur=handleBlur`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
  onBlur={e => {
    handleBlur(e);
    onBlurCallback(e);
  }}
/>
```

This would call both the callback and the handler.

Working demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-wing-xo1ip